# Problem with negative values when simulating multivariate data using rmvnorm

Tags: r, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, simulation

I'm simulating a multivariate dataset using a modified form of the `mvrnorm()` function (from the [MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html) package in R).

The problem is that I'm getting some negative values after the eigenvalue transformation (I assume) because I have many negative correlations and a number of small means.

Is there a special way to deal with this phenomenon? My idea is to just add some factor to all the datapoints (such as the 1st quartile) because I don't care so much what the exact means are, as long as the correlation structure remains intact.

A simple example:

```
require(MASS)     # For mvrnorm()
require(Matrix) # For nearPD()

corr <- diag(5)
corr[5,1] <- .5
corr[1,5] <- .5
corr[4,2] <- -.5
corr[2,4] <- -.5

set.seed(1000)
mm <- mvrnorm(n=10, mu=rep(1,5), Sigma=nearPD(corr, corr=TRUE)$mat, 
         empirical=TRUE)
```

As you can see, mm has nonpositive examples. Since I want to model physical measurements, this makes no sense.

edit2: multivariate sampling from log-normal distribution still results in negative examples:

```
mvrlnorm <- function (n = 1, mu, Sigma, tol = 1e-06, empirical = TRUE) {
    require(Matrix)
    p <- length(mu)
    if (!all(dim(Sigma) == c(p, p)))
        stop("incompatible arguments")
    eS <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE, EISPACK = TRUE)
    ev <- eS$values
    if (!all(ev >= -tol * abs(ev[1L]))) 
        stop("'Sigma' is not positive definite")
      # HERE BE log-normal distribution
    X <- matrix(rlnorm(p * n), nrow=n)
    if (empirical) {
        X <- scale(X, TRUE , FALSE)
        X <- X %*% svd(X, nu = nrow(X), nv = ncol(X))$v
        X <- scale(X, FALSE, TRUE)
    }
    retval <- eS$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(ev), length(ev)) %*% t(eS$vectors)
    retval <- X %*% retval
    retval <- sweep(retval, 2, mu, "+")
    X <- retval


    nm <- names(mu)
    if (is.null(nm) && !is.null(dn <- dimnames(Sigma))) 
        nm <- dn[[1L]]
    dimnames(X) <- list(nm, NULL)
    if (n == 1) 
        drop(X)
    else t(X)
}
```

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/420055) would help.

Comment: To add to chl's remark: it is not clear what you mean by an "eigenvalue transformation"; one cannot tell whether you are referring to negative eigenvalues or negative random values; and--most importantly--the purpose and constraints of the simulation are ambiguous, because if you can arbitrarily add "some factor" to the simulated data--which changes the means--then exactly what statistical characteristics are you attempting to reproduce with this simulation?

Comment: Added an example... sorry about that. The point of the simulation is to see if a new correlation metric for a certain kind of data can accurately recover the input correlation matrix (hence, the exact value of the means don't matter much).

Comment: What is the basis for choosing $1$ in `rep(1,5)` instead of, say, $10$, which would make your problem go away?

Comment: in my actual code, I set the means by sampling from a log-normal distribution (which is a reasonable approx of the actual physical phenomenon - population means of a community of organisms). It's not unusual for the mean of a variable to be close to 1.

Answer (score 3):

A multivariate normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}^p$ has its support equal to the whole $\mathbb{R}^p$ unless the covariance matrix does not have full rank. Therefore, there always is a positive probability to observe negative components when generating
$$
X \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\mu,\Sigma)
$$
Thus, to answer your questions:

1. The issue has nothing to do with the `mvnorm()` function. It is doing what it is supposed to do.
2. If you are imposing positivity on your distribution, you cannot use a normal distribution. Use instead a distribution restricted to $\mathbb{R}_+^p$.

Comment: I've edited the source code and replaced the normal distribution with a log normal and I still observe negative components. Want to see the code?

Comment: Indeed, I would be most interested in seeing negative log normal realisations!

Comment: added to OP. Running with same seed and correlation matrix results in negative realizations.

Comment: @zzk: your code consists in transforming an iid lognormal vector $X$ by linear transforms, i.e. $Y=\mu+A X$. The resulting vector $Y$ is no longer log-normal, since only the location families like the normal distribution remain invariant under linear transforms. And there is nothing paradoxical in observing some components of $Y$ to be negative.

Comment: This is how the mvrnorm function works as well. Is there a better way to sample from a multivariate distribution, because I haven't been able to find any functions in R that does it differently.

Comment: @zzk: exactly my point above. While it works for the normal distribution, it does not work for the log-normal distribution! This is of course an interesting problem, how to find a joint distribution on $\mathbb{R}^p_+$ with a given covariance matrix, however I do not know of a closed form solution.