# What are the distributions on the positive k-dimensional quadrant with parametrizable covariance matrix?

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, covariance

Following [zzk](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/10164/zzk)'s [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25377/7224) on his problem with negative simulations, I am wondering what are the parametrized families of distributions on the positive k-dimensional quadrant, $\mathbb{R}_+^k$ for which the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ can be set.

As discussed with [zzk](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/10164/zzk), starting from a distribution on $\mathbb{R}_+^k$ and applying the linear transform $X \longrightarrow\Sigma^{1/2} (X-\mu) + \mu$ does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that we have a multivariate normal random vector
$$
  (\log X_1,\dots,\log X_k) \sim N(\mu,\Sigma) \, ,
$$
with $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $k\times k$ full rank symmetric positive definite matrix $\Sigma=(\sigma_{ij})$.

For the lognormal $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ it is not difficult to prove that
$$
  m_i := \textrm{E}[X_i] = e^{\mu_i + \sigma_{ii}/2} \, , \quad i=1,\dots,k\, ,
$$
$$
  c_{ij} := \textrm{Cov}[X_i,X_j] = m_i \,m_j \,(e^{\sigma_{ij}} - 1) \, , \quad i,j=1,\dots,k\, ,
$$

and it follows that $c_{ij}>-m_im_j$.

Hence, we can ask the converse question: given $m=(m_1,\dots,m_k)\in\mathbb{R}^k_+$ and $k\times k$ symmetric positive definite matrix $C=(c_{ij})$, satisfying $c_{ij}>-m_im_j$, if we let
$$
  \mu_i = \log m_i - \frac{1}{2} \log\left(\frac{c_{ii}}{m_i^2} + 1 \right) \, , \quad i=1,\dots,k \, ,
$$
$$
  \sigma_{ij} = \log\left(\frac{c_{ij}}{m_i m_j} + 1 \right) \, , \quad i,j=1,\dots,k \, ,
$$
we will have a lognormal vector with the prescribed means and covariances.

The constraint on $C$ and $m$ is equivalent to the natural condition $\textrm{E}[X_i X_j]>0$.

Comment: Terrific, Paulo! You got both a working solution and the proper condition on the covariance matrix, which also answers this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/127813/14893). Log-normals prove handier than gammas, in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I have a definitely pedestrian solution.

1. Start with $X_1\sim \text{Ga}(\alpha_{11},\beta_{1})$ and pick the two parameters to fit the values of $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$, $\text{var}(X_1)$.
2. Take $X_2|X_1\sim \text{Ga}(\alpha_{21}X_1+\alpha_{22},\beta_{2})$ and pick the three parameters to fit the values of $\mathbb{E}[X_2]$, $\text{var}(X_2)$, and $\text{cov}(X_1,X_2)$.
3. Take $X_3|X_1,X_2\sim \text{Ga}(\alpha_{31}X_1+\alpha_{32}X_2+\alpha_{33},\beta_{3})$ and pick the four parameters to fit the values of $\mathbb{E}[X_3]$, $\text{var}(X_3)$, $\text{cov}(X_1,X_3)$ and $\text{cov}(X_2,X_3)$.

and so on... However, given the constraints on the parameters and the non-linear nature of the moment equations, it may be that some sets of moments correspond to no acceptable set of parameters.

For instance, when $k=2$, I end up with the system of equations
$$
\beta_1 =\mu_1/\sigma_1^2\,,\quad \alpha_{11}-\mu_1\beta_1 =0
$$

$$
\alpha_{22} = \mu_2\beta_2 - \alpha_{21}\mu_1\,,\quad
\alpha_{21} = \dfrac{(\sigma_{12}+\mu_1\mu_2-\mu_2)}{\sigma^2_1+\mu_1^2- \mu_1}\beta_2
$$
$$
\dfrac{(\sigma_{12}+\mu_1\mu_2-\mu_2)^2}{(\sigma^2_1+\mu_1^2- \mu_1)^2} \sigma_1^2 + \dfrac{\mu_2}{\beta_2} = \sigma^2_2\,.
$$
Running an R code with arbitrary (and a priori acceptable) values for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ led to many cases with no solution. Again, this does not mean much because correlation matrices for distributions on $\mathbb{R}_+^2$ may have stronger restrictions that a mere positive determinant.

**update (04/04):** deinst rephrased this question as [a new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127813/14893) on the math forum.

Comment: One way of slighly extending this is to consider the natural exponential family $$f(\mathbf{X}|\mathbf\theta)=h(\mathbf{x})e^{\mathbf\theta^T\mathbf{X}-A(\mathbf\theta)}.$$  Then the mean and covariance are the gradient and Hessian of $A$.  If $h$ is a polynomial (with real exponents > -1) then $A$ is the log of a polynomial (with real exponents), and the variance and Hessian are rational functions.  I think this gives enough freedom to represent any mean and covariance matrix.

Comment: @deinst: (+1) Do you have an example where this exponential family representation can be exploited straightforwardly?

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand the problem. But, consider a bivariate random vector $(X,Y)$ with the same marginal $F$ with full support on $\mathbb R_{+}$ and having mean $0 < \mu < \infty$. How can such a bivariate distribution have correlation $\rho$ close to -1, for example? Heuristically, though I haven't carried this out, it seems that if $\mathbb P(X > 2 \mu) > 0$, then a contradiction regarding the support must arise. No?

Comment: There are certainly constraints on the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ when the support is $\mathbb{R}^k_+$, covered via [the Stieltjes moment condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_moment_problem). Anyway, I do not see why a correlation close to -1 is excluded _a priori_.

Comment: Right, this is related to what I was getting at. Regarding the correlation, consider my example. If $X$ and $Y$ have the same marginal $F$ with mean $\mu$ and a correlation of exactly -1 and $\mathbb P(X > 2 \mu) > 0$, what must the value of $Y$ be for all such realizations of $X$? (+1 on both question and answer. I like this.)

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is a response to Xi'an's comment.  It is too long and has to much TeX to be a comfortable comment.  Caveat Lector: It is virtually certain that I have made an algebra mistake.   This does not seem to be quite as flexible as I first thought.

Let us create a family of distributions in $\mathbb{R}_+^3$ of the form
$$f(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf\theta)=h(\mathbf{x})e^{-\mathbf\theta^T\mathbf{x}-A(\mathbf\theta)}$$
Let $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)$ and $\mathbf\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$.  Let
$$h(\mathbf{x})=c x_1^{e_1-1}x_2^{e_2-1}x_3^{e_3-1}+d x_1^{f_1-1}x_2^{f_2-1}x_3^{f_3-1}$$
be a two term polynomial where $e_i, f_i$ are real numbers greater than 0 for all $i$.  Then we find that
$$A(\mathbf\theta)=\log\left(c\frac{\Gamma(e_1)}{\theta_1^{e_1}}\frac{\Gamma(e_2)}{\theta_2^{e_2}}\frac{\Gamma(e_3)}{\theta_3^{e_3}}+d\frac{\Gamma(f_1)}{\theta_1^{f_1}}\frac{\Gamma(f_2)}{\theta_2^{f_2}}\frac{\Gamma(f_3)}{\theta_3^{f_3}}\right).$$

Now, for convenience let us define
$$c'=c\Gamma(e_1)\Gamma(e_2)\Gamma(e_2)\theta_1^{f_1}\theta_2^{f_2}\theta_3^{f_3}$$
and
$$d'=d\Gamma(f_1)\Gamma(f_2)\Gamma(f_2)\theta_1^{e_1}\theta_2^{e_2}\theta_3^{e_3}$$

Now, as the mean of our distribution is the gradient of $A$, we have
$\mu_X=\frac{e_1c'+f_1d'}{\theta_1(c'+d')}$, $\mu_Y=\frac{e_2c'+f_2d'}{\theta_2(c'+d')}$, and $\mu_Z=\frac{e_3c'+f_3d'}{\theta_3(c'+d')}$. And as the covariance is the Hessian of $A$, we have
$$\sigma_X^2=\frac{(e_1c'+f_1d')(c'+d')+(e_1-f_1)^2c'd'}{\theta_1^2(c'+d')^2}$$
and 
$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\frac{(e_1-f_1)(e_2-f_2)c'd'}{\theta_1\theta_2(c'+d')}$$
(the other terms of the covariance matrix obtained by  changing subscripts in the obvious way).

This does not seem to be quite enough flexibility to get any covariance matrix.  I need to try another term in the polynomial (but I suspect that also may not work (obviously I need to think about this more)).

Comment: Four parameters $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,c)$ for five constraints...?

Comment: @xian There are the 6 exponents $e_i$ and $f_i$ as well.

Comment: I am slightly (?) confused: you did not process the exponents as parameters of the exponential family. But indeed you can change those powers as you wish towards getting the 9 moment equations right.

Comment: @Xi'an  You are correct, I did not process them as parameters of the exponential family.  Doing so would have made the family no longer a natural family, and including them would have just muddled the algebra for comuting the moment equations (which was muddled enough to begin with).